# LD Linker script EXCLUDE_FILE doesn't exclude object file from text section

Tags: c, embedded

I need to configure in an embedded application capability to writing to a QSPI NOR flash chip while execute in place (XIP) is enabled on an IMXRT106* chip. This requires me to have all function calls that change the state FLEXSPI peripheral to be located in RAM while configuration is taking place.

Using the NXP flexspi driver fsl_flexspi.c I need to locate that code in RAM via the linker script. Short from using `__attribute__((section(".ramfunc.$RAM3)))`  on every function call found in fsl_flexspi.c, I can locate those calls in ram via linker script.

I modified the linker script to:

```
...
    .text : ALIGN(4) /*Changed this section*/
    {
     *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*fsl_flexspi.o).text* ) *(.rodata .rodata.* .constdata .constdata.*)
      /* *(.text*)*/
      /* *(.rodata .rodata.* .constdata .constdata.*)*/
       . = ALIGN(4);
    } > BOARD_FLASH

...
   .data_RAM3 : ALIGN(4)
    {
        FILL(0xff)
        PROVIDE(__start_data_RAM3 = .) ;
        PROVIDE(__start_data_SRAM_ITC = .) ;
        *(.ramfunc.$RAM3)
        *(.ramfunc.$SRAM_ITC)
        *(.data.$RAM3)
        *(.data.$SRAM_ITC)
        *(.data.$RAM3.*)
        *(.data.$SRAM_ITC.*)
        drivers/fsl_flexspi.o (.text.*) <-- I added this
        . = ALIGN(4) ;
        PROVIDE(__end_data_RAM3 = .) ;
        PROVIDE(__end_data_SRAM_ITC = .) ;
     } > SRAM_ITC AT>BOARD_FLASH
```

However, I get the 'multiple definition' linking error. I can't seem to nail down the correct syntax for EXCLUDE_FILE linker script line.

Linking Error Messages

```
  arm-none-eabi-gcc -nostdlib -Xlinker -Map="FlashWrite.map" -Xlinker -print-memory-usage -Xlinker --sort-section=alignment -Xlinker --cref -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -T FlashWrite_ldde.ld -L C:/Devel/source/FlashWrite/source -o "FlashWrite.axf"  ./xip/evkmimxrt1060_flexspi_nor_config.o ./xip/fsl_flexspi_nor_boot.o  ./startup/startup_mimxrt1062.o  ./source/FlashWrite.o ./source/Uart.o ./source/dmaMemcpy.o ./source/init.o ./source/printQue.o ./source/semihost_hardfault.o  ./drivers/fsl_clock.o ./drivers/fsl_common.o ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o  ./device/system_MIMXRT1062.o   
Memory region         Used Size  Region Size  %age Used
     BOARD_FLASH:       80936 B      8160 KB      0.97%
     CONFIG_AREA:          24 B        32 KB      0.07%
         SRAM_OC:       10812 B       768 KB      1.37%
        SRAM_DTC:       17172 B       128 KB     13.10%
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_GetInstance':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:124: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_GetInstance'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:124: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_CheckAndClearError':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:197: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_CheckAndClearError'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:197: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_Init':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:243: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_Init'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:243: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_GetDefaultConfig':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:336: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_GetDefaultConfig'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:336: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_Deinit':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:390: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_Deinit'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:390: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_SetFlashConfig':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:407: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_SetFlashConfig'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:407: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_UpdateLUT':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:509: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_UpdateLUT'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:509: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_UpdateRxSampleClock':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:541: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_UpdateRxSampleClock'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:541: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_WriteBlocking':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:570: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_WriteBlocking'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:570: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_ReadBlocking':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:629: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_ReadBlocking'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:629: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_TransferBlocking':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:716: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_TransferBlocking'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:716: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_TransferCreateHandle':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:786: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_TransferCreateHandle'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:786: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_TransferHandleIRQ':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:942: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_TransferHandleIRQ'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:942: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_TransferNonBlocking':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:824: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_TransferNonBlocking'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:824: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_TransferGetCount':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:901: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_TransferGetCount'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:901: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_TransferAbort':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:928: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_TransferAbort'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:928: first defined here
c:/nxp/mcuxpressoide_11.1.1_3241/ide/plugins/com.nxp.mcuxpresso.tools.win32_11.1.0.202001081728/tools/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: drivers/fsl_flexspi.o: in function `FLEXSPI_DriverIRQHandler':
C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:1053: multiple definition of `FLEXSPI_DriverIRQHandler'; ./drivers/fsl_flexspi.o:C:\Devel\source\FlashWrite\Debug/../drivers/fsl_flexspi.c:1053: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
        SRAM_ITC:        4688 B       128 KB      3.58%
make: *** [makefile:36: FlashWrite.axf] Error 1
```

At the end you can see that there is code being allocated in the SRAM_ITC but then also elsewhere. I am out of ideas, I don't know what is going on. Thanks.

Comment: It almost looks like where you explicitly mention the file in the linker script, you are pulling it into the link a *second* time and would need to avoid the traditional command-line mention.  By why don't you use a brief descriptive #define for the section attribute and put that on the appropriate functions like everyone else does?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Well I could if I wrote the code. I know the code works via NXP example, and since its not broke, it doesn't need to be fixed. I know it is possible put whole translation modules in specific sections. Its done here, but I need to tell the linker not to include that translation module not to include those symbols in the default location. The explanation of EXCLUDE_FILE is not clear to me on how it works. The common path may not always be the best path.

Comment: Are you still passing the same object to the linker command line?  It seems you need to stop doing that, basically you are trying to link it twice.  But I still think this route is unwise - others will be used to seeing ram functions individually marked, so a future maintainer...

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm working within the IDE for NXP processors. The example I'm using as my model has this methodology in it. It makes sense to tell the linker to put this code in internal ram because when you reset the FLEXSP you are cutting off the source of instructions for the cpu after it resets the peripheral. Now I just did get the link working correctly but I still don't understand why it works, when I swear I tried that same voodoo dance last night before I posted.

Comment: Have you done anything to investigate the point already twice made, that you seem to be feeding the file to the linker twice?

Comment: @ChrisStratton Please clarify "feeding the file to linker", from my understanding I can only feed the file to linker through the command line execution of the compiler via the '-L' command switch. I looked at command invocation in the log and there is only one instance of fsl_flexspi.o . Per https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/10/06/putting-code-of-files-into-special-section-with-the-gnu-linker/ they specifically called out the directory in which object file is located. While what fixed the problem for me was changing `drivers/fsl_flexspi.o (.text.*)` to `*fsl_flexspi.o(.text*)`, why this work?

Comment: No, -L specifies a linker search directory.  -l specifies a library file.  But an object file `.o` is just mentioned on the command line.  The problem is you seem to have already mentioned it in the linker script.  I have to wonder if your "solution" actually did, are the functions ending up in the RAM section as intended?  Or is the special mention in the linker script now without a valid path getting ignored and the command line mention just resulting in a default placement in flash?  Anyway, if it works, great... I'm just... unconvinced.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I needed that code in RAM so its available to the processor, and I needed to make sure the linker didn't also put the code in the default .text location. I'm not very familiar with the linkerscript syntax and am only looking for syntax clarification. I'm glad it now works as I intended but I don't know why.

Comment: There's never been any doubt expressed by anyone that you need the code to be in RAM so why do you keep repeating that basic fact?  The issue is rather how you are doing that, and if you have in fact yet achieved that goal, vs merely gotten some link to complete without error.  What does objdump show?

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't know what you are hoping to find in the object dump. The link was successful, everything is where I need it and there is no duplicate symbol error messages. My question revolved around linker script syntax. This code is incomplete, and doesn't survive to the ending infinite loop because the peripheral isn't completely re-initialized after reset by the code.

Comment: What have you done to verify that the functions were *actually* placed in RAM, vs that the linker simply finished without error?  That's what objdump could show you...

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ah ok. Yes I look in the the map file to verify that the functions are where I need them. When testing the code and I get an unhandled exceptions which is expected, I look at the register values to see if they are representative of the memory range that the processor thinks there is data/instructions and cross check it with the map file. Object dump is good too.

Answer (score 2):

I still don't understand why my fix worked but since there were no actionable or educational answers to my question, I will post my solution. Its up to the Google user to sus out the 'why', but here is my how in my context:

Answer:
Text section here is defined. The LD documentation to me doesn't make sense to *me* on how EXCLUDE_FILE works and the use below to me looks as if its not including the other ".text" objects in the ".text section".

```
.text : ALIGN(4)
{
 *(EXCLUDE_FILE(*fsl_flexspi.o).text.*  ) *(.rodata .rodata.* .constdata .constdata.*)
   . = ALIGN(4);
} > BOARD_FLASH
```

The source of my errors above are because the linker is including the translated objects in 2 sections. In my question the output shown by the linker shows that code is being included in the SRAM_ITC.

Apparently and I don't understand why, but in the .data_RAM3 section definition the correct way, in my case is below:

```
    .data_RAM3 : ALIGN(4)
{
    FILL(0xff)
    PROVIDE(__start_data_RAM3 = .) ;
    PROVIDE(__start_data_SRAM_ITC = .) ;
    *(.ramfunc.$RAM3)
    *(.ramfunc.$SRAM_ITC)
    *(.data.$RAM3)
    *(.data.$SRAM_ITC)
    *(.data.$RAM3.*)
    *(.data.$SRAM_ITC.*)
    *fsl_flexspi.o (.text*)
    . = ALIGN(4) ;
    PROVIDE(__end_data_RAM3 = .) ;
    PROVIDE(__end_data_SRAM_ITC = .) ;
 } > SRAM_ITC AT>BOARD_FLASH
```

If the reader has Googled 'EXCLUDE_FILE' a number of "answers" will show up and hopefully this one too to muddy the waters. Some linker scripts included the path of the object file in its definition. In my case, case including the relative path was causing the LD process executed by GCC some level of grief.

The manufacturer example I was following made the necessary changes in the linker script by blanket executing all code in RAM and used XML files to describe the changes of the linker script. The IDE would then process the XML file and auto generate the linker script at build time...Not very helpful.

When it comes to writing and executing (read) from the same flash chip at the same time is generally is not possible, **unless explicitly** called out in the flash datasheet. This is called "Read While Write" (RWW). I'm using a NOR QSPI Flash which doesn't support it. This means the code that setup and write to the flash chip has to be located in RAM.

If its a single function then using `__attribute__((section(".ramfunc.$RAM3)))` would work. However, if using third-party driver code and w/o modifying the source after verified to work, using the linker script to locate the entire module is "easier", without having to modify the driver source code.

To verify the expected .text objects are where they are supposed to be, look at the objdump of the binary or the linker map file.